# Crystal report:change table name at runtime (jsp code)

Tags: mysql, jsp, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report for eclipse to generate dynamic reports(mysql database).
Till now i am able to pass parameters to the report,change the datasource connection :

```
String connectString = s.getDBpath();
String driverName = s.getClassforName();
String JNDIName = "";
String userName = s.getUserNameDB();            
String password = s.getPasswordDB();        
// Switch all tables on the main report and sub reports
CRJavaHelper.changeDataSource(clientDoc, userName, password, connectString, driverName, JNDIName);
```

the problem is that i want to change the table name , but i don't know how to do it .
i mean that i have many tables with same structure ,every user have its own table , i wanna generate the report based on the table specified for the logged in user.
is that possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those whom interested, i found the solution ,and i want share it .
all you have to do is to generate the report from a query.

add the following code to your report viewer:

```
// ****** BEGIN POPULATE WITH RESULTSET SNIPPET ****************  
            {
                // **** POPULATE MAIN REPORT ****
                {
                     // Connection Info for fetching the resultSet
                    String connectStr = s.getDBpath();
                    String driverName = s.getClassforName();
                    String userName =  s.getUserNameDB();       // TODO: Fill in database user
                    String password = s.getPasswordDB();    // TODO: Fill in valid password


                    String query = "select * from tbl2";//tbl2 is the table that you wanna make it as a report source

                    // As long the Resultset schema has the same field names and types,
                    // then the Resultset can be used as the datasource for the table
                    String tableAlias = "tbl1";     // TODO: Change to correct table alias
                   //tbl1 is the old report source,(data sr=ource for your report)

                    // Push the Java ResultSet into the report (this will then be the datasource of the report)
                    CRJavaHelper.passResultSet(clientDoc, fetchResultSet(driverName, connectStr, userName, password, query),
                        tableAlias, "");
```

hope it helps ;)